# TFS 2017 silent installation using Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to install TSF 2017 by using silent installation powershell script. I am able to install it but its not installing properly. And its not creating any folders in program files. But its showing in control panel. 
Below is the script which I am using now,

$Installer="D:\TeamFoundationServer2017_Update2\TfsServer2017.2.exe"
 $Params=@("D:\TeamFoundationServer2017_Update2\ISO\tfsserver2017.2_enu.iso","/Q","/Full","/NoRestart","/NoWeb","/Passive","/ProductKey","/Layout=C:\Users\ul\Desktop\Test","/NoRefresh","/Log=Desktop\Logfile.txt")
 & $Installer $Params

Is there anything I am missing out in $Params. Its calling exe file and executing it. In contorl panel I can able to see. But in program files its not coming. And its not installing also.

Please help me in this.

Comment: You are passing a log parameter `/Log=Desktop\Logfile.txt`, have you checked that file? It might also have problems with the relative path there, but I'm not familiar with that installer.

Comment: Yes I have checked and its empty

Answer (score -1):

`TfsServer2017.2.exe` is a web installer, it will download TFS from VisualStudio.com and kick off the installation. However, the installation process itself **simply gets TFS bits onto your machine.** At the end of this process, the installer will launch the **TFS Configuration Center**.

[image]

Even select Basic scenario(*This scenario is optimized for simplicity, using default options for most inputs*), you will still need to choose and enter many configuration.

More details please refer: [How to set up TFS on a single server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/install/single-server)

Besides, this is only suitable for a single server scenario, you could also install TFS under [Dual server](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/install/dual-server)/ [Multiple server configuration](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/install/multiple-server) . Highly doubt this could be done through a single powershell script.

You could also have a look at this tutorial -- [Team Foundation Server 2017 Installation Guide](https://www.benday.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/benday-tfs2017-install-guide-v1.1.pdf)

---

If you just want to want to use PowerShell DSC resources to install configure a TFS build agent, please refer [this](https://github.com/PowerShellOrg/TeamFoundationServer) code source in GitHub.

Comment: @Meghana  It's not able to install TFS slient with TFS server config. There are two many configurations for the server. And why you want to install the TFS server through a script. Since usually we don't have to install TFS frequently, it's no need  or no worth to script it.

Comment: Actually its client's requirement

Comment: This answer is not an answer on how to silently install TFS. This might seem strange in Microsoft world, but it is supposed to be a tool for automation, yet an answer on how to manually install it is the answer presented.